# View Based NSTableView Not showing data

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I have a view-based TableView that I am adding trivial data. However the view is not populating correctly.

```
 - (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView {

int rows=2;

return rows;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn  row:(int)rowIndex {

// The return value is typed as (id) because it will return a string in most cases.


NSTableCellView *aTableCellView = [aTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:aTableColumn.identifier owner:self];

if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstName"]) {
    aTableCellView.textField.stringValue = @"Mike";
}

if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"LastName"]) {
    [aTableCellView.textField setStringValue:@"Bagger"];
}

return aTableCellView;

}
```

[image: NSImageView]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your `NSTableCellView` subclass and its child views, from Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use view-based tables (and already have an `NSTableCellView` subclass defined in Interface Builder), you should instead override and implement the `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` *delegate* method:

[NSTableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:)

This method should contain the body of your implementation above, populating and returning the `NSTableCellView` that you've created.

Comment: It is incorrect that `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is only for cell-based tables. It is optional for view-based tables. The object value returned is set on the cell view if it responds to `-setObjectValue:`, which `NSTableCellView` does. So does `NSTextField` if that's what one uses for the cell view. You're correct that lack of `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is often a cause of blank tables (although his isn't blank), but it's not required. If the column identifier and cell view identifier match, the cell view can be created without that method.

Comment: @KenThomases You are correct, I will update my answer. Thank you for clarification - I didn't realize you could use `objectValue...` with view-based tables.

Answer (score -1):

You should just return the value for the column instead of setting it explicitly. So, instead of doing

```
aTableCellView.textField.stringValue = @"Mike";
```

you should just write

```
return @"Mike"
```

So, your code should look like below:

```
if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstName"]) {
    return @"Mike";
}

if ([aTableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"LastName"]) {
    return @"Bagger"];
}

return nil;
```

Comment: -1: This answer is only applicable if using cell-based tables, but OP specified view-based, and is trying to return a `NSTableCellView` in his implementation.